# Result exam certification by email

Tags: email, certification

I passed today adm201 certification exam but I have not received any results email with pdf and logo on my email account. I checked spam folder also but nothing. On webassessor it results pass. What should I do??

Comment: This got bumped to the front page by the system... anybody know if these are still valid ways to raise a case?

Answer (score 1):

2019 Update:

[trailhead link for creating a case](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help) or mail at certification@salesforce.com

Answer (score 0):

I would open a case within Salesforce Web Assessor.  When you are logged in, you will see a link that will allow you to open a case.  (See Below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case and open a case with following category selection

[image]